# The set and get methods of a property on the prototype aren't shadowed from the corresponding property on the instance which has no set-get methods

Tags: javascript

I have the following code from [Eric Faust ES6 class syntax sugar](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/07/es6-in-depth-classes/):

```
function Circle(radius) {
      this.radius = radius;
      Circle.circlesMade++;
  }

  Circle.draw = function draw(circle, canvas) { /* Canvas drawing code */ }

  Object.defineProperty(Circle, "circlesMade", {
      get: function() {
          return !this._count ? 0 : this._count;
      },

      set: function(val) {
          this._count = val;
      }
  });

  Circle.prototype = {
      area: function area() {
          return Math.pow(this.radius, 2) * Math.PI;
      }
  };

  Object.defineProperty(Circle.prototype, "radius", {
      get: function() {
          return this._radius;
      },

      set: function(radius) {
          if (!Number.isInteger(radius))
              throw new Error("Circle radius must be an integer.");
          this._radius = radius;
      }
  });

  let x = new Circle("pippo");
```

And I can't understand why is launched the exception. The setter and getter methods are associated with the prototype `Circle.prototype` on the `radius` accessor property instead when I create the `x` instance I set the radius property too but in the constructor function thus I expected that setter and getter weren't triggered (again because `radius` property on the instance and `radius` property on the prototype are defined on two different objects) . I miss something about how setter and getter work in this case. Someone can clarify me?

Furthemore another little unrelated question, is it right define the *static* property `circlesMade` on the constructor `Circle` or was it more correct to define it on the prototype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the constructor, the assignment to `this.radius` is an assignment to the "radius" property of `this`. The value of `this` is of course the newly-created object, and the prototype chain of that object is already set up by the time the constructor code runs. Thus the setter for "radius" will definitely be called, and you'll get the exception.

The setter and getter methods are indeed on the prototype, but the whole point of doing that is to make it so that every instance shares that behavior. The object referenced by `this` in the constructor function is one of those instances.

For "simple" prototype properties that don't have getter/setter functions, assignment to `this.whatever` in the constructor function or anywhere else will always create a property *locally* on the target object instead of changing the property value on the prototype. Properties with getter/setter methods don't work that way.

Note that the code in the constructor function does not follow different rules than code in any other function. Special things happen on the way in to the function and on the way out, but otherwise it's plain ordinary code.

Comment: The `circlesMade` property is correctly placed on the constructor function object.

Comment: Set and get method are associated to a property, radius on the prototype, and since that radius on the prototype is shadowed from radius property on the instance(this) I thought set-get methods weren't triggered (because they aren't associated to the radius property on the instance).  But apparently this is not the case.

Comment: Yes, it is not the case. When a property on the prototype is a getter/setter property, it is basically a special kind of *method* property on the prototype. Thus the rules for method invocation apply.

Comment: It's detailed in typically obtuse language in section 9.1.9 of the ES2015 spec. If the property is resolved to be a getter/setter property, the normal behavior of creating a new *instance* property is skipped, and the setter is called.

Comment: Thanks. This comment is the answer that hits my doubt. Please put in your main answer , if you want, so I can accept this answer to solve my problem (and for future audience).